# python how do i use abs for clockwise?

Tags: python

im trying to get absolute value between base_pos and postiion but clockwise.

```
position = [9,12,6]

base_pos = 3


position = sorted(position, key=lambda k: abs(k - base_pos))

print (position)
```

the code above will give the result of this

```
[6, 9, 12]
```

my desired result

```
[6, 12, 9] #or 
[12, 6, 9]
```

but i want to get [6,12,9] or [12,6,9] because for a clock, 3 is closer to 6 and 9 than 12.
is there any way to accomplish this using abs? if not, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by clockwise? Could you explain what your overall goal is?

Comment: is to find the close number of base_pos but in clockwise. for example, if base_pos is 12, the output would be either [3,9,6] or [9,3,6].

Comment: I think this is really a question about math, not a question about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing distance (0 to 11) in both directions and taking the smaller:

```
sorted(position, key=lambda k: min((k-base_pos)%12, (base_pos-k)%12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is on here

```py
from math import cos, pi

position = [9,11,6,1,2,4,5,7,8,10,12,3]

base_pos = 3


position = sorted(position, key=lambda k: -cos((k%12 - base_pos) * pi / 6))

print (position)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Is the %12 needed?

Comment: I thought hours in 24-hour times will be used so that I did `%12`